# oracle sql error- missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, database, oracle, error-handling

I read almost everything similar questions to mine and i didn't come up with the answer.

I've written a query for Horses Database.
There i want to make a list with horses that never finished first in any of their participations in all meetings they have participated in.My query is:

```
SELECT H1.Horse_ID,H1.H_compressed_name

FROM Horse H1

WHERE NOT EXISTS

      ((SELECT P1.Part_ID

       FROM participation P1)

       EXCEPT(  --line *

          SELECT P2.Part_ID

          FROM participation P2,Horse H2

          WHERE P2.H_ID=H2.Horse_ID AND P1.Part_ID=P2.Part_ID  
                AND H1.Horse_ID=H2.Horse_ID));
```

I get this error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis" 
*Cause:     
*Action:
```

in line *.

But im not if sure if the problem is a missing right parenthesis indeed.Any help pls??

Comment: Does the participation table include a field to indicate finishing position? The query as it stands doesn't appear to look for horses that failed to finish first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle equivalent of EXCEPT is MINUS - also, no link is required from the exception set to the excepted set, and I think some of the brackets may be redundant in the query in the question; I suggest the following:

```
SELECT H1.Horse_ID,H1.H_compressed_name
FROM Horse H1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT P1.Part_ID
       FROM participation P1
       MINUS
       SELECT P2.Part_ID
       FROM participation P2,Horse H2
       WHERE P2.H_ID=H2.Horse_ID AND 
             H1.Horse_ID=H2.Horse_ID);
```

- to fix the query, although I don't think it will return the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with the other poster that EXCEPT is the problem.  I wonder though if what he's trying to get at is:

```
SELECT H1.Horse_ID,H1.H_compressed_name
FROM Horse H1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT P1.Part_ID
       FROM participation P1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (  --line *
          SELECT P2.Part_ID
          FROM participation P2,Horse H2
          WHERE P2.H_ID=H2.Horse_ID AND P1.Part_ID=P2.Part_ID  
                AND H1.Horse_ID=H2.Horse_ID));
```

In this case there's an extra left parenthesis causing the specific error.